# Change data on column, when finished working with row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName();
    var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = e.range.getRow();
    var Val = e.range.getValues();

    if(sheetName == "firstTable"){
        range.setNote(Val.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Example my table

[image: image exel table]

I want to change the result when all the data in the cells has been filled on

"Model Number", "Spec 1", "Spec 2", "Spec 3 ", "Spec 4 "

trigger `onEdit()` for this is not suitable. Tell me how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you want, but based on your example, try this formula in F2:

```
=arrayformula(if(MMULT( --(LEN(A2:E)>0) , TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:E2)^0))=5,"Retail",""))
```